# "lazy evaluation" and "reactive programming"

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, reactive-programming

With examples can someone demonstrate how lazy evaluation is different than reactive programming. Alternatively, are they very similar?

---

Given `c = 3;` both approaches would seem to involve implementing `b = c + 2;` at least internally regardless of how the code looks as `int b() {return c + 2;}`. In both cases it's not known what `b` is until its value is required, then the calculation occurs.

What would the name be that describes this approach?

---

So reactive programming uses or simulates lazy evaluation? Languages with lazy evaluation are programmed in a reactive way?

Comment: 'lazy evaluation' is a reduction strategy, 'reactive programming' is a programming style, usually with lazily defined structures, so they don't really sit at the same abstraction level.  It's unclear to me what you mean by "functionally"

Comment: Still slightly confused, because you need to scope your question correctly: for example, functional reactive programming in Haskell (the programming style) could be contrasted with call by need reduction (a *feature* of the language, used in supporting FRP).  Logically, one sits at a "lower level" than the other.  But this may not be the answer you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be confusing lazy evaluation and reactive programming as being at the same "logical level."

To me, lazy evaluation is a language facility that allows the existence and manipulation of infinite data.  (Data that has a sort of "finite structure" but is infinite in the sense that you can pull off as much as you want and still have some left over.)  If you scratch your head a bit and try some examples, you will see that having lazy evaluation is good in the presence of infinite data structures because you don't "loop forever" when using these values.  (Though there are other uses for lazy evaluation as well, there are certainly some performance gains to be had at times.)

Wikipedia defines reactive programming:

> In computing, reactive programming is a programming paradigm oriented around data flows and the propagation of change. This means that it should be possible to express static or dynamic data flows with ease in the programming languages used, and that the underlying execution model will automatically propagate changes through the data flow.

To me, this doesn't really go with lazy evaluation at all.  Lazy evaluation just means that you only compute as much of an answer as you need to do more work, and then keep around a holder (typically called a "thunk") that will let you do more work when you need it so you can compute more answers.  (By the way, this ability to pull off "as much as you need" is exactly what allows you to play with infinite data using lazy evaluation.)

By contrast, reactive programming allows you to define --- succinctly --- how data flows will be propagated.  (For example, a reactive framework would let you set up that example you gave *without* explicitly having to implement it using callbacks and function pointers.)  But in reality, this line is very fuzzy.  There are certainly reactive frameworks in imperative languages: most people will call GUI frameworks reactive.

By contrast, in [functional reactive programming(FRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming), you declaratively specify reactive data.  This is implemented "under the hood" using the laziness of the Haskell language (in that particular case) because that is the method most amenable to doing updates (since it most directly fits that paradigm).

But in language like C or C++, you typically do reactive programming via function pointers or callbacks, without an explicit notion of lazy evaluation.   Sure, there will probably be some laziness under the hood to support this kind of stuff, but you aren't really at the right semantic level to make that distinction, and in this case you can usually use lazy 'tricks' to speed up the reactive framework (which ostensibly updates something --- say the GUI --- on demand as the user uses more pieces of it).

Comment: I think I might get it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've landed on this post as I had exactly the same question. The answer is excellent. I believe that both myself and the OP were asking this since if you look at libraries like Bacon.js or Lazy.js, it really seems that under the hood their implementation can easily be realised by using the reactive paradigm (eg, with streams). As you hinted, reactive programming has nothing to do with infinite sets, but the problem I'm facing could benefit from lazy evaluation without infinite sets (a filter on a large set of data).